# return max value from pandas dataframe as a whole, not based on column or rows

Tags: python, pandas, max, dataframe

I am trying to get the max value from a panda dataframe as a whole. I am not interested in what row or column it came from. I am just interested in a single max value within the DataFrame.

Here is my DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group1': ['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','d','d','d','d','d'],
                        'group2': ['c','c','d','d','d','e','f','f','e','d','d','d','e'],
                        'value1': [1.1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4],
                        'value2': [7.1,8,9,10,11,12,43,12,34,5,6,2,3]})
```

This is what it looks like:

```
   group1 group2  value1  value2
0       a      c     1.1     7.1
1       a      c     2.0     8.0
2       a      d     3.0     9.0
3       b      d     4.0    10.0
4       b      d     5.0    11.0
5       b      e     6.0    12.0
6       c      f     7.0    43.0
7       c      f     8.0    12.0
8       d      e     9.0    34.0
9       d      d     1.0     5.0
10      d      d     2.0     6.0
11      d      d     3.0     2.0
12      d      e     4.0     3.0
```

Expected output:

```
43.0
```

I was under the assumption that `df.max()` would do this job but it returns a max value for each column but I am not interested in that. I need the max from an entire dataframe.

Comment: is `max(df.max(axis=1))` what you want? this assumes you are just interested in numerical values only?

Comment: Also the [online docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html#pandas.DataFrame.max) are quite clear on what `df.max()` does,

Comment: why the downvote? I misunderstood the df.max() if that was the reason?

Comment: don't know, wasn't me I don't have much of a problem with this question

Comment: Wasn't direct at you EdChum, but thanks a lot for your input! a lot to learn...

Comment: `df.max().max()`

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The max of all the values in the DataFrame can be obtained using `df.to_numpy().max()`, or for `pandas < 0.24.0` we use `df.values.max()`:

```
In [10]: df.to_numpy().max()
Out[10]: 'f'
```

The max is `f` rather than 43.0 since, in CPython2,

```
In [11]: 'f' > 43.0
Out[11]: True
```

In CPython2, [Objects of different types ... are
ordered by their **type names**](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons). So any `str` compares as greater than any `int` since `'str' > 'int'`.

In Python3, comparison of strings and ints raises a `TypeError`.

---

To find the max value in the numeric columns only, use

```
df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).max()
```

Comment: Also `max(df.max())` will also return `'f'` maybe worth pointing out

Comment: So, how to skip strings and obtains the maximal numeric value?

Comment: @Sigur: `df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).max()`.

Comment: How to do this for a specific column: `col1` for example? I tried `df['col1']` but not.

Comment: `df['col1'].max()` should return the max value in the `col1` column. If that doesn't work for you, please post a new question containing a small sample of your dataframe (posting something like `df.head().to_dict('list')` helps a lot).

Comment: The problem is that `df['col1'].max()` returns a string `foo` (which is in data frame entry) but I want only the numeric maximum. I didn't post it cos I'm afraid that it is duplicated. I can not find yet.

Comment: Oh, now I see. Use `pd.to_numeric(df['col1'], errors='coerce').max(skipna=True)`.

Answer (score 64):

Hi the simplest answer is the following.
Answer:

```
df.max(numeric_only=True).max()
```

Explanation: 
`series = df.max()` give you a Series containing the maximum values for each column. 
Therefore `series.max()`gives you the maximum for the whole dataframe.

`numeric_only` is required when strings are involved; as @unutbu's answer points out, the result for the OP's question would otherwise be `f` in python 2 and `TypeError` in python 3.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative way:

```
df.melt().value.max()
```

Essentially `melt()` transforms the DataFrame into one long column.

Comment: Note this doesn't work for the OP's question, when there are strings in the df

Answer (score 5):

using numpy max

```
np.max(df.values)
```

or

```
 np.nanmax(df.values)
```

or in pandas

```
df.values.max()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Note this doesn't work for the OP's question, when there are strings in the df.

Answer (score 1):

For the max, check the previous answer...
For the max of the values use e.g.:

```
val_cols = [c for c in df.columns if c.startswith('val')]
print df[val_cols].max()
```

Answer (score 1):

Max can be found in these two steps:

```
maxForRow = allData.max(axis=0) #max for each row
globalMax = maxForRow.max(); #max across all rows
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45681145/3427777) is probably best for the general case, but if you need speed, and your values are limited to known columns, specifying your columns first will use less cpu cycles. For example:

```
df[['value1', 'value2']].max(numeric_only=True).max()
```

You can drop the `numeric_only` if the specified columns are known to contain only numbers.