# Position of maximum value in column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am newbie to this python.Consider i have 2 columns in a dataframe as follows:

```
A    B
2    6
3    7
4    8
```

Now the maximum in column B is 8 and i need the value in column A for that, here its 4. Please help to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24571005) [question2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10202570) [manual method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [idxmax()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) to get the index of max value, and then reference the index value in column A

```
In [7]: df.ix[df['B'].idxmax(), 'A']
Out[7]: 4
```

Where

```
In [8]: df['B'].idxmax()
Out[8]: 2
```

Comment: Thanks @John Galt , I got it.Dont mistake me, if i want to get the previous value in column A. Then how can i accomplish it.