# Fill with default 0's when creating a DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an input dict-of-string-to-list with possibly different lengths for the list.

```
d = {'b': [2,3], 'a': [1]}
```

when I do: `df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)`, 
i'm seeing **ValueError: arrays must all be same length**

**Question**: How do i fill the missing values with default (e.g. 0) when creating the df?

---

The reason to create the df is to get the final result of:
`{'b': 3}`

whereas `3` is the max of all numbers in the lists.

Comment: You can look into similar question for multiple methods: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736080/creating-dataframe-from-a-dictionary-where-entries-have-different-lengths In addition, you need `fillna` after creating the dataframe.

Comment: [df.max().max()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45681145/3380951) gets the max value 3 once the df is created

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) setting `orient` to `index` so the keys of the dictionary are used as indices and the missing values are set to `NaN`. Then simply fill `NaNs` using [`.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and transpose to set the keys as columns:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').fillna(0).T

    b    a
0  2.0  1.0
1  3.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {'b': [2,3], 'a': [1]}
df = pd.DataFrame({ k:pd.Series(v) for k, v in d.items() })
```

This will give the following output.

```
a  b
0  1.0  2
1  NaN  3
```