# how to create DataFrame with Series of Arrays with different Length(missing data in some sections)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

im trying to Clean and organize some data i got from a price list about laptops specs.
the problem is that some laptops description has less attributes or more, so when i try to convert to Dataframe, i cant reshape it given each array has a different length. Ill try to explain more with my code.

I have first split the description of each laptop by comma (using str.split), and from there i wanted to create but i got an error saying "cannot reshape array of size 14 into shape (14,10)" i tried many ways but nothing.

After split, i tried to use pd.Dataframe, but it was giving me errors of cannot reshape array of size 14 into shape (14,10).
i dont know how to approach the problem

```
desc1 = 
"1UG81UAR#ABL - Intel Core i7-7700HQ 2.80GHz, 8GB, 2TB, 
15.6""FHD(1920x1080), AMD Radeon RX550 2GB, 802.11ac+BT, Cam+Mic, 
Win 10, Refurb 90-Days"
"3NS58AAR#ABA-WH2L - Intel Core i7-8750H 2.20GHz, 8GB, 1TB+16GB 
Optane SSD, 15.6""FHD(1920x1080), NVIDIA GeForce 4GB, 802.11ac+BT, 
Cam+Mic, Win 10, Factory Refurb 90-Days"
"3NS58AAR#ABA-WH39 - Intel Core i7-8750H 2.20GHz, 8GB, 1TB+16GB 
Optane SSD, 15.6""FHD(1920x1080), NVIDIA GeForce 2GB, 802.11ac+BT, 
Cam+Mic, Win 10, Factory Refurb 90-Days"
"D3L06LAT#ABM - AMD E1-1500 1.48GHz, 2GB, 500GB, 14""HD(1366x768), 
Radeon HD 7310, DVDRW, 802.11bgn, Cam+Mic, Win 8.0Pro, Refurb 90- 
Days"
"2XH17AAR#ABA-WH1P - AMD A9-9420 3.00GHz, 4GB, 128GB SSD, 
15.6""HD(1366x768), Radeon R5, 802.11ac+BT, Cam+Mic, Silk Gold, Win 
10, Factory Refurb 90-Days"
"4NC74UAR#ABA - AMD Ryzen 5-2500U 2.00GHz, 8GB,128GB SSD, 
15.6""HD(1366x768), Radeon Vega 8, 802.11ac+BT, Cam+Mic, Win 10, 
Factory Refurb 90-Days"
"P0E23LAT#ABM - AMD A10-8700P 1.80GHz, 16GB, 1TB, 
15.6""HD(1366x768), Radeon R7 M360 2GB, DVDRW, 802.11ac+BT, Cam+Mic, 
Win 10, Refurb 90-Days"
"2NM72UAT#ABA - AMD A6-9220 2.50GHz, 4GB, 500GB, 15.6""HD(1366x768), 
Radeon R4, 802.11bgn, Cam+Mic, Win 10, Refurb 90-Days"
"4JB82UAR#ABA - AMD A9-9425 3.10GHz, 4GB, 1TB, 15.6""HD(1366x768), 
Radeon R5, DVDRW, 802.11bgn+BT, Cam+Mic, Win 10, Factory Refurb 90- 
Days"
"2DX36AAR#ABA-WKHN - Intel Core i7-7500U 2.70GHz, 12GB, 128GB SSD, 
15.6""HD(1366x768) Touchscreen, Intel HD, 802.11ac+BT, Cam+Mic, Jet 
Black, Win 10, Factory Refurb 90-Days"
"2DX36AAR#ABA-WLTX - Intel Core i7-7500U 2.70GHz, 8GB, 128GB SSD, 
15.6""HD(1366x768) Touchscreen, Intel HD, 802.11ac+BT, Cam+Mic, Jet 
Black, Win 10, Factory Refurb 90-Days"
"2DX36AAR#ABA-WLN6 - Intel Core i7-7500U 2.70GHz, 8GB, 128GB SSD, 
15.6""HD(1366x768) Touchscreen, Intel HD, 802.11ac+BT, Cam+Mic, Jet 
Black, Win 10, Factory Refurb 90-Days"
"W7B99UAT#ABL - AMD  A8-7410 2.20GHz, 8GB, 1TB, 15.6""HD(1366x768) 
Touchscreen, Radeon R5, 802.11bgn, Cam+Mic, Win 10, Refurb 90-Days"
"3WE70UAR#ABA - AMD Ryzen 5-2500U 2.00GHz, 8GB,1TB, 
15.6""HD(1366x768) Touchscreen, Radeon Vega 8, 802.11ac+BT, Cam+Mic, 
Win 10, Factory Refurb 90-Days"
```

dataframe =

```
    Model          Proc        MEM   HD   size     Vid    GH  Mic...

0  1UG81UAR#ABL    Intel Core  8GB   2TB  15.6...  AMD... 802...

1  3NS58AAR#ABA    Intel Core  8GB   1TB..15.6..   NVIDIA..
                   i7...
```

I am trying to split and then create a Dataframe, so then i can sun some Linear regression on the specs.
I would appreciate any type of help please

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/54657930/9698684

Comment: @yatu i got this error 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Comment: i tried everything and i stil cant do it