# How to find the max, min value of ALL Dataframe [ not values by column neither rows ]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max, min

I know how to find in a Dataframe the max and minimum value of a column:

```
df.min()
df.max()
```

If I want to find the min and max values by row is:

```
df.max(index=1)
df.max(index=1)
```

But this return a list with the respective row or column value. I want to find the minimum or maximum value of all the dataset, only one value.

I was thinking try to iterate by row and column finding the max value But I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/9550633) that this is anti-pattern for pandas.

I am thinking in a function that only output me a value with the respective location. This function exist or I need to create?

I research answer here and not find anything related.

Comment: `df.max().max()` ?

Comment: See [return max value from panda dataframe as a whole, not based on column or rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571005/return-max-value-from-panda-dataframe-as-a-whole-not-based-on-column-or-rows).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
max_val = df.max().max()
```